# Can this be interpreted as an invocation expression in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax

According to the C# grammar, one can write

```
(A)(B)
```

which can be interpreted either as an invocation expression or a type cast.
Can someone please provide a valid C# example that interprets this case as an invocation expression?

This is the grammar rule I'm referring to:

```
invocation-expression:
    primary-expression   (   argument-list?   )
```

and `primariy-expression` can be a parenthesised expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
((Action<string>)Console.WriteLine)("test");
```

Or this, as an expression:

```
((Func<int>)Console.Read)()
```

**Edit:** I doubt there is a way for `primary-expression` to be a simple identifier, as this always gets parsed as a cast (even `(writeLine)()`), but it's not a big deal, as you can always just remove the parentheses.

Comment: Anything with a single Identifier? Can something like this, say (Id)(Args?), also exist? (so that the resulting expression be ambiguous and can be interpreted as a cast)

Comment: @Ali You'd think so: `Action<object> writeLine = Console.WriteLine; (writeLine)(writeLine);` seems like it could be valid. It gets rejected though: it gets parsed as a cast, so compilers (Microsoft's and Mono's) complain that there is no type named `writeLine`, and that a cast is not a valid expression statement. So I suspect the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Visual Studio complains about this: `(TestMethod)();`

But this is evaluated as a function call (assuming TestMethod is a method): `(this.TestMethod)();`

Unless TestMethod is static, in which case even `(MyClass.TestMethod)();` doesn't work.

I think it's because something like `this.TestMethod` unambiguously evaluates to a method group. There is no scenario where `this.anything` would evaluate to a type. But `classname.something` could be a nested type, or it could be a static method, so VS seems to interpret that as a type.